# Using different Apple IDs for device and iTunes Store

Tags: itunes

Is it possible to have one Apple ID for a device, and a different Apple ID for the iTunes Store on the same device?

In Settings, where do I find the Apple ID entry for the iTunes store?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a different Apple ID for iCloud services and iTunes, yes, that is possible. On iOS, your iCloud login is in Settings / iCloud and your iTunes login is under Settings / iTunes Store and Apps. On OS X, your iTunes login is in iTunes under the Store menu, and iCloud is under System Preferences / iCloud.

Note that the iCloud login is tied to your iCloud account, your icloud.com/me.com/mac.com email address, and other services. If you are actively using that email address, you may not be able to switch to the Apple ID you use in iTunes.

Apple does not currently provide a way to merge Apple IDs.

Comment: Also changing appleId's for iTunes and App Store can create problems when apps downloaded under the old appleId want to update.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was getting at. You can really only do this if you can abandon the iCloud address; you'll always need to keep the iTunes login for app purchases to update and to redownload any music, movies or TV. I'm stuck with both myself until Apple lets us merge them.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned bellow, however you will have some trouble updating app as this is not a expected behavior.

E.g sometimes you will have to connect to the another appleID un order to complete an update

also obviously for redownload past purchase you will have to connect on the correct AppleID also when disconnect , you automatically get disconnect from Apple Music.